# get request in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my jquery code on location: C:\Users\HUSSAM\Desktop\Example\js\init.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
   $('#button').click(function(){
     var text = $('#input').val();    
     $.get('reverse.php', {text:text} ,function(data){    
        alert(data); //don't get this msg!!
        $('#msg').text(data);    
     });
  });
});
```

And here is the php code on location: C:\Users\HUSSAM\Desktop\Example\js\reverse.php

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_GET['text']) != ''){echo $_GET['text'];}    
?>
```

Guys why i am not getting the response in alert box. I am running the index.php from this location: C:\Users\HUSSAM\Desktop\Example\index.php

Comment: Are you running a local http server that supports PHP? or are you using file:/// protocol - the latter wont work for PHP at all

Comment: I am running it using file:/// protocol

Comment: then PHP wont get "processed" - because you don't have anything running to process the PHP side of things

Comment: Should i run index.php file using xampp?

Comment: Thanks problem solved.. I ran php file using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the file open in the browser, but you don't have an actual server running it. I'd suggest looking into something like MAMP for OSX or XAMPP for windows.

Comment: Thanks, It works when i run php file using xampp. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have pass object fo parameters on `$.get()` method but you can try something other solution link this to convert object into querystring using `$.param()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
   $('#button').click(function(){
     var text = $('#input').val();    
     $.get('reverse.php?'+$.param({text:text}) ,function(data){    
        alert(data); //don't get this msg!!
        $('#msg').text(data);    
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
 $('#button').click(function(){
 var text = $('#input').val();    
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "reverse.php",
 data:{ text : text  }, 
 success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    alert(data) 
    }
  })
 });
});
```

and this is php code

```
<?php    
  if(isset($_GET['text']) != ''){
  echo $_GET['text'];
}    
?>
```